# htaccess redirect when url does not contain a string

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have following site structure

```
 - root 
     - de/index.htm
     - en/index.htm
```

When the user requests the site and has not defined the language like

```
 mysite.com
```

instead of

```
mysite.com/en/
```

I want him to be redirected to the en folder. Because the root folder does not contain any files actually. I am not really familiar with apache rewrite rules. This is what I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule ^/en/index.htm
```

But this does not work. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have isn't correct syntax, you've got 2 `RewriteCond` in a row followed by what looks like the actual condition, then a rule that has no target. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^/?$ /en/index.htm [L]
```

If you want what's in the browser's URL address bar to change, add an `R` flag to the brackets:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /en/index.htm [L,R]
```